# Traversal in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

1. Why is value in the `Entry` class of `ConcurrentHashMap` volatile.
2. During traversal, there is a check in `ConcurrentHashMap` that when the `value` in the `Entry` class in null, it locks the whole segment and tries to read the value again. In which case can the value alone be null? The whole entry should go null and not only the value.
3. And how locking the whole segment ensures correct traversal in case the value comes null.

Answer (score 1):

1. The value is volatile primarily so that the ConcurrentHashMap does not need to block on reads.  When `put`'ing the CHM will lock the segment to guarantee one put per segment but other Thread's are still allowed to read from that segment, and since the value is volatile the CHM still maintains a happens-before ordering.
2. The JMM allows for a volatile store in a constructor to be delayed or reordered after the object has been published.  So it could be possible that, even though the Entry is published, the volatile field has yet to be made visible.  This was put in to be 'extra-safe' but in practice wouldn't happen (in Java 6 at least)
3. When the put is made, it is done so under the Segment's lock.  When acquiring that same lock you guarantee the subsequent write will be now visible to any reads after said write (this is another guarantee for Lock and synchronized where a write occurring under a lock will be visible to any future reads under the same lock, this does not hold true for a lock write and a volatile read however).

Comment: I don't understand the line in the first answer "and since the value is volatile the CHM still maintains a happens-before ordering." However, 2nd and 3rd answers are clear to my understanding.

Comment: With this concept I will explain more, "The ConcurrentHashMap should not block on read's (should not have to acquire the segment lock when reading), but must also guarantee all writes are up-to-date with subsequent reads" The only way this can be done is if the write to the value of the Entry is volatile. Since it is volatile any subsequent read to the Entry.value (after a write) is guaranteed to see the most up to date value.

Comment: Ok. But why 'value' again needs to be volatile  for 'happens before' ordering when we already have whole 'table'(transient volatile HashEntry<K,V>[] table;) itself volatile in the Segment inner class of CHM?

Comment: Oh that is a different case.  The array itself being volatile does not effect the entries of the array (so assigning a `table[1] = new HashEntry()` has no special memory semantics).  The table needs to be volatile because it's reference may change when having to do a restructuring.

Comment: Oh yes. That's correct. Could 'key' being volatile instead of value also serve the purpose? (asking this to ensure what I understood is correct!)

Comment: It wouldn't help only because the key would never have to change, and because of that the field is created as final (which holds different more strict guarantees then volatile).  Imagine if you did a put(1, new Object());  then later did another put(1, new Object());.  The Entry already exists, the key is the same you just need to do a volatile write on the HashEntry.value